# Is it possible to have a generic constraint that uses an index(type or object)?

Tags: typescript, generics

I am code-generating client models(Entities) as well as corresponding Primary Keys.

I would like to have a method signature whereby predicated on the Entity, the 2nd param should be its Primary Key only.

The following use of type / class are not a requirement and may become interfaces or const for the map etc..

What I have tried is:

```js
export type ClassType<T> = new (...args: any[]) => T

export class CustomerPk {
  customerId: number;
}

export class VendorPk {
  vendorId: number;
}

export class Customer implements CustomerPk {
  customerId: number;
  name: string;
}

export class Vendor implements VendorPk{
  vendorId: number;
  name: string;
}

export type EntityType = Customer | Vendor;
export type EntityPk = CustomerPk | VendorPk;

export type entityToPkMap = {
  Customer: CustomerPk, Vendor: VendorPk
}
```

To consume like so:

```js
  constructor() {   
    const myCust = this.GetData(Customer, new CustomerPk());
    const myVend = this.GetData(Vendor, new CustomerPk());  // I want this to guard at design time.
  }
  
  // Can I(how) structure the generated code 
  //  to be able to consume similar to the following?
  public GetData<T extends EntityType, K>(entity: ClassType<T>, primaryKey: K): T {
    // Get from store.
    throw new Error('Not Implemented');
  }
```

I have tried variations of the following without finding what I am looking for:

```js
public GetData<T extends EntityType, K extends entityToPkMap[T]>(entity: ClassType<T>, primaryKey: K): T
```

Which errors with "Type 'T' cannot be used to index type 'entityToPkMap'."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#conditional-types) to resolve primary key type:

```
type PkMap<T> =
    T extends Customer ? CustomerPk :
    T extends Vendor ? VendorPk :
    never;

class Foo {
    constructor() {
        const myCust = this.GetData(Customer, new CustomerPk());
        const myVend = this.GetData(Vendor, new CustomerPk()); // expect error
    }

    public GetData<T>(entity: ClassType<T>, primaryKey: PkMap<T>): T {
        throw new Error('Not Implemented');
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDCAbAhgZxwFWWAB58A+OAXjgDtgB3OACgDo2soBzHALjixqIA2gF0AlFQr4A3AFgAUAtCRYcAMbY86AK44YEALbAoABQDWcAN4K4t9bv1GoASQAmAQj41tBgEbG5eQBfBSVwaHgNXBw4ADVgGldocysbOwA3BKSXDy8ffyhAkMV5ZQj1TRi0B0NjOABLAzAMYCMaGCqapxTreTt7PVqcz1p8gLTbGiwjEb0oeppOItDS8NUorXjE6AamlraOuKzki17+zO3hvL9xvrspmb45haWFYoUkFDhzAFksMFIFEoEzg+DgoBgWU6gyccAA-DoYcYUjwQWCIVCjpd4VjsiiQXRMoUVhsYgAxCAQVJ3WxqCA0ObaNT6KBMCRnfp2OkM+AGRDVPRUBAAC3qOBYAHFgDAACJYGBYJgCxzGAA0tAYiJVpjMbLEgU5XPpgr5W1cQpgovFUtl8sVZug6rojGVQ3MeoNdneNLgYG0vgw9TUcBtcoVgKYCRg9SQfEw0UIKEB6rA8wMHEQAGlgIg+L9-oCxHwwRzDZaoBBGM64ABRKAV1kAcgAchB4M49q0o8BXI39SDikEgA)

Comment: Oh that's awesomeness!  Thank you :)

Comment: Other option would be adding static type discriminator (string) to each class, then building the map (similar to what you've tried). One more option - attaching primary key constructor as a static property of class constructor..

Comment: This meets what I need perfectly.  PrimaryKeys can be interfaces and when inputting; Ctrl + space (in VSCode) suggests PrimaryKey Prop name.

Comment: After some implementation, our ~75 Entities cause the following error: `Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.ts(2589)`.  I can make 'the red squigglies' go away in VS Code by using TS > 3.9 but am using Angular with doesn't support TS > 3.9 just yet.  :/  Link: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37613#issuecomment-604218540

Comment: Here's a working one https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-bassi-mekby?file=/src/index.ts (playground generates too long one for comment)